# Generate persistance mapping from database schema In IntelliJ15

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea, mapping

i'm using IntelliJ 15.0.3,I connect oracle database 10g,then i want to create jpa entity.

> open Import Database Schema Dialog,and Choose a table named:CD_AREA_DICT

[image: Import Database Schema Dialog]

> When Click ok ,I get the error:Cannot generate Mapping xml.

[image]

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select XML mapping file (usually orm.xml) in your project or simply add new one using [+] button. You can also uncheck "Generate Single Mapping XML" and generate entities without creating/updating mapping file.

To avoid unrecognized mapped types you should probably add JAVA to your project classpath.

[image: IntelliJ JPA Entity Generation]

Comment: Hi Marek, In ma case, the text field "Generate Single Mapping XML:" is not editable and there is no "+" button on the right side of it. Do you know the reason and how to fix that, please?